# a simple Calculator, Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, calculator

At first, I have a calculatorBrain:

```
@interface calculatorBrain : NSObject {
    NSString *theOperator;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *theOperator;

-(float)performOperation:(float)a andOperandB:(float)b;
@end
```

Then, a function in `ViewController`, linked to a `button`.

part of ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize result, brain;

-(IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"AC"]) {
        result.text = @"0";
    } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        if (0 == [result.text rangeOfString:@"."].length)
        result.text = [result.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    } else {
        brain.theOperator = sender.currentTitle;
        NSLog(@"%@", brain.theOperator); // return (null)
    }
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *result;
    calculatorBrain *brain;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *result;
@property (strong, nonatomic) calculatorBrain *brain;

-(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
-(IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

The question is, why do I set nothing after I pressed the `button`? Thanks!

Comment: Did you alloc and initialize the object of calculatorBrain i.e. brain?

Comment: i cant use sender.currentTitle, I alwasy use `[sender currentTitle]`

Comment: "sender.currentTitle is no NULL!" are you sure of this? Apple documentation states that this property may be nil.

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", sender.currentTitle);`?

Comment: @Rushi Where should I do this?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya it's just same.

Comment: @PlusA : i know, but in my xcode4.5, i dont know why . is not working for this method only :(

Comment: @ohho it's output (null), marked in the code :)

Comment: before:
-(IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
// Here initialize the object brain
    if([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"AC"]) {
        result.text = @"0";

Comment: @Rushi It just work, thanks so much! But if I have many method share a same obj (like calculatorBrain), how do I choose where should I alloc and init it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 -(IBAction)operatorPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        brain = [[calculatorBrain alloc] init] autorelease];
        if([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"AC"]) 
        {
            result.text = @"0";
        } 
        else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"."]) 
        {
            if (0 == [result.text rangeOfString:@"."].length)
                result.text = [result.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
        } 
        else 
        {
            brain.theOperator = sender.currentTitle;
            NSLog(@"%@", brain.theOperator); // return (null)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PlusA: If you have multiple calls. Then just alloc it once in viewWillAppear. It'll work.

Comment: maybe alloc it in - (void)viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @PlusA : yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it looks like you are expecting this property to be synthesized. You can read more about this in [various tutorials on the web](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/04/objective-c-tuesdays-property-and.html).

The exact behaviour will depend on the Obj-C version used. I would recommend that you read the above tutorial in order that you can better understand your code.

Comment: I guess if he is using xcode4.4 onwards, it will be synthesized automatically.

Comment: @ColinE I put more code now, I have synthesized the calculatorBrain *brain. Thanks!